# Email notification for failed SSH login

Tags: centos, ssh, email, login

Can someone tell is there a way to receive an email for failed SSH login? I already have Fail2Ban but as understood I can receive only email's for banned IP's ...
Using CentOS 7

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know about fail2ban, but failed logins are logged in `btmp` and `/var/log/audit/audit.log`. Scan them on a regular basis and send yourself an email whenever a log entry is made.

Comment: As you stated that, IMO it's bad idea. At least think about some thresholds or some better filtering - ie. login from a privileged user/group or from a suspicious IP range.